# Can you disable the VS feature that keeps separate window positions for Debugging and Editing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I don't have the need to have my Visual Studio windows in different locations when editing versus debugging. In fact, I'd prefer my windows to stay where I put them, and not jump around as I switch between editing and debugging.

Is there a way to tell VS to not keep different window settings for the two modes?

I'm currently using VS 2005 if that matters.

Thanks,
-Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than manual editing of an exported settings file, to copy one layout over another then importing, no.

Remember it isn't just window positions, but which ones are open, and debug generally includes additional debug only windows (call stack, threads, watch, ...).